# How to use searchasync of Dropbox API v2

Tags: c#, .net, dropbox-api

I'm currently using official Dropbox.NET SDK of API v2 for developing a Universal Windows Platform app. I use Dropbox to store images. And I want to perform searching in root directory of my Dropbox folder and get return of the matches results.

In this context, I would like to get metadata as follow:

1. Path for downloading
2. Thumbnails of the images

Anyone knows how to do it? I had gone through the documentation of Dropbox.NET. But I have no idea of how to do it. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for the [ListFolderAsync](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesRoutes_ListFolderAsync_1.htm) and [GetThumbnailAsync](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesRoutes_GetThumbnailAsync_1.htm) methods.

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks for the suggestions. Yes, I have gone through the methods, however, the ListFolderAsync give me Matches, where I don't know how to get metadata from it. Do you have any working code for me to learn? Thanks 

Comment: The tutorial has a simple example of using ListFolderAsync: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/dotnet#tutorial There are also several sample apps that may be helpful: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/dotnet#overview